# Knockout Declarations

Tags: knockout-2.0

I am new for knockout. I would like to know the differences between these three and which one is best as per latest framework.

Approach 1 (InvoiceTypes): Declaring all variables and methods using comma and finally using return statement to expose  public interface methods.

Approach 2 (OrderTypes): It is similar to Approach 1 but used semicolon to differentiate each variable or method.

Apprach 3 (ModelTypes): It is similar to Approach 2 but with out return statement.

Finally specified calling way of start method in each approach in jquery read.

***Approach 1***

```
    window.Domain = window.Domain || {}
    window.Domain.InvoiceTypes = function () {

        var types = ko.observableArray(),
        getTypes = function() { return types; },
        start = function() {
            types.push({name:"knockout"});
        },
        submit = function() {
            alert("submit");
        };

        return {
            getTypes: getTypes,
            start: start,
            submit: submit
         };   
   }();
```

***Approach 2***

```
    window.Domain.OrderTypes = function () {

        var types = ko.observableArray();

        var getTypes = function() { return types; };

        var start = function() {
            types.push({name:"knockout"});
        };
        var submit = function() {
            alert("submit");
        };

        return {
            getTypes: getTypes,
            start: start,
            submit: submit
         };   
   }();
```

***Approach 3***

```
    window.Domain.ModelTypes = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.types = ko.observableArray();
        self.getTypes = function() { return types; };
        self.start = function() {
            types.push({name:"knockout"});
        };
        self.submit = function() {
            alert("submit");
        };

   };

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

         window.Domain.InvoiceTypes.start();

         window.Domain.OrderTypes.start();

         var obj = new window.Domain.ModelTypes();
         obj.start();
       });
   </script>
```

The difference I can see clearly is, single var declaration & return statement and using of self by this keyword.

Please provides your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Approaches #1 and #2 are akin to static factory methods. Rather than creating an object with the `new` keyword, you are calling a static "factory" function that creates and returns a new type for you. As for the comma versus semicolon approach, both are valid, but I prefer semicolons over commas. Why? Because javascript is more forgiving with semicolons than with commas. You can omit a semicolon here and there and the script will still run, whereas commas must always be present for the javascript to be correctly parsed. It is also easier to read with semicolons when your script gets larger.

Approach #3 is what most knockout developers do, or should to. Firstly, because you don't need the little `()` at the end of your function declaration, so it looks more like a class. However, it looks like you have an error in there:

```
self.start = function() {
    //types.push({name:"knockout"}); // types was not declared,
    self.types.push({name:"knockout"}); // only self.types was declared
};
```

... same error here

```
self.getTypes = function() {
    //return types; types was never declared
    return self.types;
};
```